# The numbers in the array are not displaying from the first number in file

Tags: c

The txt file contains 10000 elements starting from 2148 to 9269, but after storing them in array and displaying the elements does not print elements from start.Though the last element is being displayed perfectly.

I have tried searching the web but not able to find an exact solution.I have tried the code in python also. After storing the elements in list if displayed the whole list output is perfect but if I convert them from string to int and then print one by one same problem arises.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j=0,a[10000];
    long long int c=0;
    char str[MAXCHAR];  //MAXCHAR is defined as 10
    char filename[80] = "C:\\Users\\Akshat\\Desktop\\codes\\C\\QuickSort.txt";

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp)!=NULL)
    {
      int len=strlen(str);
      int num=0;
      for(i=1;i<len;i++)
        num+=(str[len-(i+1)]-'0')*pow(10,i);
      a[j]=num/10;
      j++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
  }
```

The same happens if I print str inside loop. First element displayed in from somewhere between.Also, the total number of elements when printed, prints 10000 which is right.

here's a link to the file - https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_32387ba40b36359a38625cbb397eee65_QuickSort.txt?Expires=1546473600&Signature=Tapm7qDg-hFcSkGtF6~zP5uDxoVK3cr4p-vePsnONjcd46aCAS9BZQGAry3gBmAd0upm3WbFJSosVdl1Owj~AY8bhlKvNbyiOMg9oYdko0ax4-PKRtP0NjyXa-Q35equ7YQmp3W4r3RAYb9hO-bQnpX1Q-JNIntYvV3rk4GUmdc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

Comment: C or C++? It cannot be both.

Comment: In a recent similar question, the text had rolled off the top of the console buffer.

Comment: please show the output you are actually getting with this code you tried

Comment: Will you always have at least 10000 entries put into the array `a`? If there could be less then part of the array will be uninitialized and have *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) values. And in C++ even the act of reading such values leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher It's C.

Comment: I guess perhaps the `prinf("%s",...) ` it needs an immediate break thereafter coz the cursor waits rather appending in the loop has caused the undefined behaviour

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yup, a fixed set of random 10000 values.

Comment: The output I'm getting in both lang is a huge list of numbers from 7895 to 9269.

Comment: why do you read the numbers _by hand_ after reading the string rather than just do a `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[j++]);` ?

Comment: I tried this with your input file and it output the same 10000 numbers. Have you tried directing the program output to a text file and examining that with a text editor?

Comment: The way to read numbers as text and convert to numbers is a bit strange and will fail if there is some whitespace after the number

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a small subset of your file and it does work fine for me. I think you are storing the number of elements in the variable j and you should use that instead of having a fixed number of 10000 in the print loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    const int MAXCHAR=10;
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j=0,a[10000];
    long long int c=0;
    char str[MAXCHAR];  //MAXCHAR is defined as 10
    char filename[80] = "test.txt";

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp)!=NULL)
    {
      int len=strlen(str);
      int num=0;
      printf("%s",str);
      for(i=1;i<len;i++)
        num+=(str[len-(i+1)]-'0')*pow(10,i);
      a[j]=num/10;
      j++;
    }
    printf("STARTING THE ARRAY PRINT\n");
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
  }
```

> To compile

```
gcc -o cque cque.c -lm

output
2148
9058
7742
3153
6324
609
7628
5469
7017
504
4092
1582
9572
1542
5697
2081
4218
3130
7923
9595
6558
3859
9832
3062
6788
7578
7432
479
8439
9079
7173
2667
2770
2655
972
4264
2014
3171
STARTING THE ARRAY PRINT
2148
9058
7742
3153
6324
609
7628
5469
7017
504
4092
1582
9572
1542
5697
2081
4218
3130
7923
9595
6558
3859
9832
3062
6788
7578
7432
479
8439
9079
7173
2667
2770
2655
972
4264
2014
3171
```